# Retrieve list from table with 2 columns using ExecuteSql

Tags: c#, sql, .net, db2

I am trying to retrieve a List from a SQL command. I'm doing this

When I run the query with a hard coded parameters I am getting the 2 columns (B1BRNB, PREMIUM) but i am unable to get them in c sharp using the bellow code. I'll appreciate any help!

```
public class Premiums
{
    public int B1BRNB { get; set; }
    public double PREMIUM { get; set; }

    public List<string> GetPremiums(string policyId)
    {
        var policy = _quoteRepository.GetPolicy(policyId);
        string sql = "SELECT B1BRNB, SUM(SARPREM) AS PREMIUM " +
                     " FROM PMSPSA15BR JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(B1J4TX),B1BRNB " +
                     " FROM ASB1CPPBR WHERE B1ASTX = '@PolicyId' AND B1ADNB = '@Module'  ) a " +
                     " ON (B1J4TX = SARUNIT) " +
                     " WHERE POLICY0NUM = '@PolicyId' AND MODULE = '@Module' "+
                     " GROUP BY B1BRNB " +
                     " ORDER BY B1BRNB";


        var match = _dataContext.ExecuteSql<Premiums>(
                    sql,
                    new DB2Parameter("@PolicyId", policy.Id),
                    new DB2Parameter("@Module", policy.Line.Module)).ToList();


        return match;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In here

```
"WHERE B1ASTX = '@PolicyId' AND B1ADNB = '@Module'  ) a"
. . . . . .  .
"WHERE POLICY0NUM = '@PolicyId' AND MODULE = '@Module' "
```

Remove single quotes

```
"WHERE B1ASTX = @PolicyId AND B1ADNB = @Module  ) a"
. . .  . . . . 
"WHERE POLICY0NUM = @PolicyId AND MODULE = @Module "
```

When you use parameters, you don't surround them by quotes because than, they are treated as string values